# Matplotlib fig.legend, legend title overlaps with legend contents

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

When I try to add a title to my figure legend using fig.legend, the title box overlaps with the legend contents. I have tried adjusting the borderpad and labelspacing but that hasn't fixed it. Here is my code for the legend:

```
fig.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.9), loc="upper right", title="Wind Direction", fontsize=12)
```

And here is a picture of what the legend looks like, with the overlapping title:

[image: Figure legend]

And here is the full figure for reference:

[image: Full figure]

Comment: with so many items you might wish to split this graph into 2-3 graphs with fewer lines for the sake of readibility

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added a picture to my post showing what the full figure looks like. Because of the nature of the data I'm working with it's important to show several different variables all on the same figure.

Comment: You could try using a smaller font, or multiple columns in the legend. Or maybe use a colorbar instead? Does it work better if you start the legend higher? Which matplotlib version are you using? Did you try `ax.legend()` outside the plot, instead of `fig.legend()`  (note that calling `plt.tight_layout()` at the end usually fits everythin nicely into the figure)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference if I change the location of the legend. Changing font size might work but I don't want the text to be too small. I will try ax.legend. I am using matplotlib 3.2.1

Comment: Using ax.legend fixes the title overlap problem, but creates the new problem of displaying the legend next to both plots in the figure (I think because I am using "ax2 = ax1.twinx()" to duplicate the x axis)

Comment: You really might want to try to upgrade to the latest matplotlib version. The overlapping title problem doesn't seem to exist in version 3.4.2. Also, a `twinx` ax shouldn't be a problem, just make sure to leave enough space to start the legend, e.g. `ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 1.02), loc='upper left')`

Comment: Orthogonal comment, but scatter takes a c argument and then you can use a colorbar rather than a legend.  You may also decide to use a cyclic colormap, since 359 and 1 degree are basically the same, but here they suddenly jump in color.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks.